# Stick an image button to the right edge of an iframe overlay

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have my resume in an iframe div that overlays my portfolio section when a link in my nav is clicked. I have an "X" image for user to click to close overlay, and I want to place it to the right of the resume iframe (ie: it butts up against the outer right edge of the iframe).

I can't seem to figure out how to do this - I tried using various different float, positioning and margin setups but the closest I can get is where the "x" is on the right side but its position moves with the window rescaling. I would like for it instead to "stick" to the right edge of the resume and stay there! Is there a way to do this? Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<header>
<nav></nav>
</header>

<div id="resume-overlay">
    <div id="resume">
        <iframe src="resume.html"></iframe>
        <a href="#"><img class="button" src="img/x-button.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="portfolio">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    height: 80px;
    width: 1600px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#resume-overlay {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 80px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.resume {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1600px;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

And my jQuery if needed:

```
$(function() {
    $('#overlay').on('click', function() {
        $('#resume-overlay').fadeToggle('fast');
    });

    $(".button").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.back(1);

        $('#resume-overlay').fadeToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

[To illustrate, I want to move that blue X to the right edge of the white box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrHRQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure they type of error you're seeing yet, but your code here:

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

Is all I think you need to address, try adding

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

And remove the padding, work with those values to get the button where you want it, and it shouldn't move from those setting regardless of window size.

Comment: Thanks but when I do that the X sticks to the right edge of the window and moves when window is rescaled. I added an image to the post so you can see what I mean...